# Problem with for each node in xml (vb.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net, loops

The node.SelectSingleNode function retrieves data only from the first iteration. The values remain the same in the next iteration.
When I check the node object, I see that it changes its data as every iteration.

My code:

```
    Function readDataFromXML(xmlString As String)
        Dim xmldoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
        Dim status As String
        xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlString)

        '  Console.WriteLine(xmlString)


        'for each dokumentyEzla
        Dim dataWygenerowania As String = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//dataWygenerowania").InnerText
        Dim adresEmail As String = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//adresEmail").InnerText

        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/raportEzla/dokumentyEzla")
        Console.WriteLine(nodes.Count)
        For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerXml)
            status = node.SelectSingleNode("//status").InnerText

            Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & status)
            status = ""
        Next node
    End Function
```

Nodes change text, but parameters which I try get have value from first node (for example status).

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W4tT.png)

xml attached

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<raportEzla>
    <daneRaportu>
        <dataWygenerowania>2018-08-01</dataWygenerowania>
        <adresEmail>użytkownik.testowy@zus.pl</adresEmail>
        <platnik>
            <nip>1112223344</nip>
            <nazwaSkrocona>Nazwa Skrocona Platnika</nazwaSkrocona>
            <identyfikator>
                <typ>D</typ>
                <wartosc/>
            </identyfikator>
        </platnik>
        <typRaportu>Jednorazowy</typRaportu>
        <zakresDokumentow>Raport jednorazowy, dla dokumentów Wystawione w okresie: od 2018-03-01 do 2018-05-31</zakresDokumentow>
        <dolaczDokumentyXml>false</dolaczDokumentyXml>
        <liczbaDokumentowEzla>3</liczbaDokumentowEzla>
    </daneRaportu>
    <dokumentyEzla>
        <daneUbezpieczonego>
            <identyfikator>
                <typ>PESEL</typ>
                <wartosc/>…<wartosc/>
            </identyfikator>
            <imie>MARIA</imie>
            <nazwisko>NOWAK</nazwisko>
        </daneUbezpieczonego>
        <daneDokumentu>
            <seria>ZZ</seria>
            <status>Anulowane</status>
            <numer>123456</numer>
            <dataWystawienia>2018-04-20</dataWystawienia>
            <dataZus>2018-04-20</dataZus>
            <okresZwolnienia>
                <dataOd>2018-04-20</dataOd>
                <dataDo>2018-04-29</dataDo>
            </okresZwolnienia>
            <okresWSzpitalu>
                <dataOd/>
                <dataDo/>
            </okresWSzpitalu>
            <kodChorobyA/>
            <kodChorobyB/>
            <kodChorobyC/>
            <kodChorobyD/>
            <kodChorobyE/>
            <wskazaniaLekarskie>2</wskazaniaLekarskie>
            <miejsceUbezpieczenia>1</miejsceUbezpieczenia>
            <czyAnulowane/>
            <kodPokrewienstwa/>
            <dataUrodzeniaOsoby/>
        </daneDokumentu>
    </dokumentyEzla>
    <dokumentyEzla>
        <daneUbezpieczonego>
            <identyfikator>
                <typ>PESEL</typ>
                <wartosc/>…<wartosc/>
            </identyfikator>
            <imie>JAN</imie>
            <nazwisko>KOWALSKI</nazwisko>
        </daneUbezpieczonego>
        <daneDokumentu>
            <seria>ZZ</seria>
            <status>Skorygowane</status>
            <numer>101001</numer>
            <dataWystawienia>2018-04-20</dataWystawienia>
            <dataZus>2018-04-20</dataZus>
            <okresZwolnienia>
                <dataOd>2018-04-21</dataOd>
                <dataDo>2018-04-30</dataDo>
            </okresZwolnienia>
            <okresWSzpitalu>
                <dataOd/>
                <dataDo/>
            </okresWSzpitalu>
            <kodChorobyA/>
            <kodChorobyB/>
            <kodChorobyC/>
            <kodChorobyD/>
            <kodChorobyE/>
            <wskazaniaLekarskie>1</wskazaniaLekarskie>
            <miejsceUbezpieczenia>1</miejsceUbezpieczenia>
            <czyAnulowane/>
            <kodPokrewienstwa/>
            <dataUrodzeniaOsoby/>
        </daneDokumentu>
    </dokumentyEzla>
    <dokumentyEzla>
        <daneUbezpieczonego>
            <identyfikator>
                <typ>PESEL</typ>
                <wartosc/>…<wartosc/>
            </identyfikator>
            <imie>SYLWIA</imie>
            <nazwisko>ZIMOCH</nazwisko>
        </daneUbezpieczonego>
        <daneDokumentu>
            <seria>ZZ</seria>
            <status>Wystawione</status>
            <numer>123456</numer>
            <dataWystawienia>2018-04-20</dataWystawienia>
            <dataZus>2018-04-20</dataZus>
            <okresZwolnienia>
                <dataOd>2018-04-20</dataOd>
                <dataDo>2018-04-27</dataDo>
            </okresZwolnienia>
            <okresWSzpitalu>
                <dataOd/>
                <dataDo/>
            </okresWSzpitalu>
            <kodChorobyA/>
            <kodChorobyB/>
            <kodChorobyC/>
            <kodChorobyD/>
            <kodChorobyE/>
            <wskazaniaLekarskie>1</wskazaniaLekarskie>
            <miejsceUbezpieczenia>1</miejsceUbezpieczenia>
            <czyAnulowane/>Nie<czyAnulowane/>
            <kodPokrewienstwa/>
            <dataUrodzeniaOsoby/>
        </daneDokumentu>
    </dokumentyEzla>
    </raportEzla>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution.
I took a value from the whole xml, instead of just from a specific area.

```
status = node.SelectSingleNode("descendant::status").InnerText
```